# Replicated ActiveMQ Artemis server - messages are not replicated

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have configured the ActiveMQ master and slave servers.

In case of failure of the master the slave is set as the active server, but previous messages from the master are not available.

Master configuration (broker.xml):

```xml
      <connectors>
        <!-- Connector used to be announced through cluster connections and notifications -->
        <connector name="artemis">tcp://192.168.2.200:61616</connector>
        <!-- connector to the slaves -->
        <connector name="slave1-connector">tcp://192.168.2.112:61616</connector>
      </connectors>

      <ha-policy>
         <replication>
            <master>
               <!--we need this for auto failback-->
               <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
            </master>
         </replication>
      </ha-policy>
      
      <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>
      
      <cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>
      
      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
            <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
            <static-connectors>
               <connector-ref>slave1-connector</connector-ref>
            </static-connectors>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
```

Slave configuration (broker.xml):

```xml
    <connectors>
        <!-- Connector used to be announced through cluster connections and notifications -->
        <connector name="artemis">tcp://192.168.2.112:61616</connector>
        <!-- connector to the master -->
        <connector name="master-connector">tcp://192.168.2.200:61616</connector>
    </connectors>

      <ha-policy>
         <replication>
            <slave>
               <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
               <!-- not needed but tells the backup not to restart after failback as there will be > 0 backups saved -->
               <max-saved-replicated-journals-size>0</max-saved-replicated-journals-size>
               <failback-delay>2000</failback-delay>
            </slave>
         </replication>
      </ha-policy>

      <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>
      <cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>
      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
            <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
            <static-connectors>
               <connector-ref>master-connector</connector-ref>
            </static-connectors>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
```

What's wrong with these configurations?

Comment: Ough... It wasn't... Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for messages to be replicated they must be *durable* (i.e. persistent). By definition non-durable messages are volatile and are therefore not replicated.